# Android List doesn't slide down

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

I'm at the very beginning of Android.

While I've been playing around with the views, I've encountered this problem, googled a little bit but couldn't find anything. I've listed some rows(textviews) horizontally.(See the picture). My problem is I cannot slide down the list to see the elements below. For slide to work, should I add some library/function/xml value?

What am i missing?

This is part of my java code (i take the data from the db and put it on screen with a while loop)

```
LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myList);
TextView t = new TextView( getApplicationContext() );
t.setText("some text");
t.setClickable(true);
l.addView(t, 250, 30);
```

and my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    android:text="Add"    
    />    
<EditText    
    android:id="@+id/title"    
    android:singleLine="true"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    />
<EditText    
    android:id="@+id/body"    
    android:singleLine="true"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myList" 
    >
    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/ok"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:text="Ok -----------> "  
        /> 
    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/delete"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:text="Delete All"  
        /> 
</LinearLayout>

<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/list" 
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `TextView` to hold your list of strings.

You should use a `ListView` for your list. It will be scrollable by default.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) you have a full sample of a `ListView` that holds a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `ScrollView` to get a scrollbar.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html